# Trying to Create a new A Record for a Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-route53

Good day everyone!

I'm using boto3 to create an A record to point to a load balancer that I've created.  When I try to send the following record:

```js
aws_response = route53.change_resource_record_sets(
    HostedZoneId=_hostedZoneId,
    ChangeBatch={
        'Comment': 'Creating a record',
        'Changes': [
            {
                'Action': 'CREATE',
                'ResourceRecordSet': {
                    'Name': _name,
                    'Type': 'A',
                    'TTL': 15,
                    'AliasTarget': {
                        'HostedZoneId': _aliasHostedZoneId,
                        'DNSName': _instanceAlias,
                        'EvaluateTargetHealth': False
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
)
```

I'm getting the response:
2017-08-11 11:41:16,775 WARNING  An error occurred (InvalidInput) when calling the ChangeResourceRecordSets operation: Invalid request

Which is really vague and I'm trying to figure out where my input is bad.

Here is the values of my variables, maybe the format is incorrect:

```
_hostedZoneId = 'Z3BCDEFG3AAAAA' (changed it)

_name = 'subdomain.domain.com'

_aliasHostedZoneId = 'Z12BBB3BBB4B5B'

_instanceAlias = 'somename-1234567890.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com'
```

Thank you very much for looking this over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load balancers in us-east-1 are always aliased from HostedZoneId `Z35SXDOTRQ7X7K`. This value is public information.  That string goes in your variable `_aliasHostedZoneId`.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/elb.html

The HostedZoneId in the root of the request is *your* hosted-zone-id.  It's difficult to tell from your sanitized values but it looks as if you have the wrong values, or you might have transposed these two values.

For Alias records, the TTL is always inherited, so it also appears to be invalid to specify a TTL, here.

Comment: You're right, it was just the TTL record was not needed!

Thank you very much for your help!